# count number entry in a CSV file using javascript in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, csv

I am trying to check the file extension and count number of entry in the CSV file. At the moment the file extension check worked. My problem is the count of number row in the CSV at the moment when i run the code the count is 1 but the file selected has more than one entry. Any help please

HTML

```
   <input type="file" name="attachmentcsv" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" class="form-control" id="attachmentcsv" />
```

JavaScript

```
   var _validFileExtensions = [".csv", ".CSV"];
  function ValidateSingleInput(oInput) {
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
                var lines = sFileName.split('\r').length;
           // Check if the CSV file is valid and count the number of entry
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {

                        // show row count in the CVS file. Error is here
                           alert("CVS file has  " + lines + " Numbers");

                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry the file, " + sFileName + " selected is invalid, file extensions allowed are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(" , "));
                    oInput.value = "";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

code below works for me

```
    document.getElementById('attachmentcsv').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
    function readSingleFile(evt) {
        //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
        var f = evt.target.files[0];
        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();              
            r.onload = function (e) {
                var contents = e.target.result;
                var lines = contents.split("\n").length;
                // Remove header count
                var mobileEntryCount= lines -1
                if (mobileEntryCount <= 1) {
                    $('#csvcount').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#csvcount').text('CSV File Selected has  ' + mobileEntryCount + ' Mobile Number Saved');
                } else {
                    $('#csvcount').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#csvcount').text('CSV File Selected has  ' + mobileEntryCount + ' Mobiles Number Saved');
                }   
            }
            r.readAsText(f);
        } else {
            alert("Failed to load file");
        }
    }
```